# How to save a NetCDF file with proper timestamp in R?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have simply made everything ready for saving my `NetCDF` but during saving the file I cannot save the timestamp as before.
Previously, the timestamp was `1970-01-01 00:00:00.0` and the unit `hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0`, see the first picture. When I save it, I get the same unit, but the hours change and not the months, see second picture.
This is how I save my NetCDF file:

```
shp = st_read("path/shapefile.shp")
temp = brick("path/temperature70-78.nc")

nc.mask = mask(temp, shp)
writeRaster(nc.mask, filename = "path.nc", overwrite = TRUE, format = "CDF", varname = "t2m", varunit = "K", longname = "temperatuer in 2 metres", xname = "longitude", yname = "latitude", zname = "time", zunit = "hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0")
```

[image: untitled]

[image: untitled2]

Comment: Please provide a self-contained, minimal, reproducible example that illustrates your problem. Not images.

Comment: Maybe the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67439371/13818750) can help?!